# Broken clay drainage pipe

Tags: drainage

Have a broken clay drainage pipe that just takes water away from the house.  It is near the wye on the bigger clay drainage pipe that where the difficulty is.  So any ideas how to fix it?
[image]
E we

Comment: What kind of water? Gray , black, gutter runoff? It looks clean but may affect how I would answer.

Comment: Rain water only

Comment: that corner looks like it was dodgy when it was new,

Answer (score 2):

Use 5-inch to 4-inch Fernco reducers to fit the OD of the 4-inch clay pipe and connect them to a new length of SD35 PVC pipe. Cut the clay pipe with a masonry blade with a circular saw or angle grinder. A cheap black masonry blade will to the couple of cuts you need no problem.

Answer (score 1):

With rain water only it is much easier. I am guessing that is 4” inside diameter clay pipe, I would excavate a bit more and cut the bell on the left or dig back to the next section. With both ends open purchase some flexible drainage pipe (commonly used for a French drain). Split the flex and put it over the clay and then cover the end where it is split with plastic. Then backfill and it will be fine for as long as the clay holds up. This is a small job and a heavy duty garbage bag wrapped around the split at rack end will work to keep dirt out. So you cut the end of the flex put it over the clay at each end then cover with the plastic trash wrapping snug at each end or opening. Backfilling with gravel is best but the dirt that was removed can be used for backfill,

If this was for sewer my answer would be much different but rain water it could be even something solid over the break then plastic to keep the dirt out , I have had patches like this last for quite a few years when another section failed and I replaced the entire line.

Comment: Might try it out

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest that you have 2 options:

1: If you have scope to build a manhole / inspection chamber over that point on the pipe, you could do that, possibly with little change to the pipe required.

2: Replace the broken pipe. (Note: here, I’m assuming UK practices...) You’ll need to expose more of the pipe and obtain new pipe, Y-junction, and couplings. (Also note that the socket pipes pictured are not as available in the UK as they used to be and new pipes tend to be slightly different sizes). There are a couple of different options to accommodate the pipe sizes - bandseal couplings (basically a rubber coupling with Jubilee clips to tighten to fit the pipe) or the propriety couplings to adapt the new pipe to the old size pipe. (To use these, you may need to cut the centre out of the coupling to allow it to slide right over one pipe and back again once the pipes are positioned).

Comment: This is the only place it is broken at.  Difficult to replace the rest of the clay tile pipes.

Comment: Would it be easier to do something about where the bend is near the broken pipe .

Comment: A manhole sounds like a lot of work to me for a small break like this.